# How to draw DensityPlot on a given association?

Tags: plotting, associations

I want to draw a DensityPlot similar to below:-

```
DensityPlot[Sin[x] Sin[y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

But my problem is, I am not given the function itself. I am given the values (or association) of the function. That is, I am given `asso` as below:-

```
grid1 = Outer[{#1, #2} &, Range[-4, 4], Range[-3, 3]]
value1 = Table[N[Sin[x] Sin[y]], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}]
asso = Thread[Flatten[grid1, 1] -> Flatten[value1, 1]]
```

How can I draw DensityPlot by using `asso` (low resolution is not a problem)? I tried all 4 approaches as below, but all are failed:-

```
asso2 = Association@asso
DensityPlot[asso, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}]
DensityPlot[asso2, {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}]
DensityPlot[asso]
DensityPlot[asso2]
```

Many thanks!

Comment: [`ListDensityPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListDensityPlot.html)?

Comment: Thanks. `ListDensityPlot@
 MapThread[
  Insert[#1, #2, -1] &, {Flatten[grid1, 1], Flatten[value1, 1]}]` works!

Comment: equivalently: `ListDensityPlot[Append @@@ asso]`

Comment: maybe `Dataset[asso2][ListDensityPlot]` or `Query[ListDensityPlot]@asso2`?

Answer (score 2):

Use

```
f = Interpolation[asso /. Rule -> List];
DensityPlot[f[x, y], {x, -4, 4}, {y, -3, 3}]
```

[image]

Comment: Alternatively, `f = Interpolation[List @@@ asso]`.